# Managing child worker threads list

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, polling, fire-and-forget

After so much research, I thought I should ask the experts.

I am working on a project for my corporate employer, we have android and iPhone mobile apps that make request to a web service, the request is logged in pending state for processing.

A windows service retrieves the pending requests and spins a new thread for every request. This is because the request could be directed to different providers who process request in different manners. One could immediately process the request and return feedback, others could receive the request and take up to 30 seconds to return a feedback which you have to poll for the status.

The mobile app will also be polling for the status of the request.

Now my challenge is:

I am thinking of creating a list of threads say 100 and assign each thread to execute a request, once finished the thread will be recreated and assigned a new request. It is a high response based platform so I am thinking of not using ThreadPool.

Is it advisable to spin new threads in a fire and forget sequence or manage these list of threads and if it is to managed, then what is the best approach to manage these list of threads and ensure high performance in C# as the mobile apps will be polling for a response.

Regards

Comment: As far as I understand, your service receives jobs and spins a thread to process that job. This is all cute but you would gain more flexibility and ability to control and debug stuff if instead of threads you would make your service pass start-up information to an endpoint application and started the process.

Comment: @albertdadze Your question would likely get better responses on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @T.S. Please can you help clarify what you mean by endpoint application? I was looking at spinning the parameterized thread and leaving it to do the work from start to finish. The thread would even do the polling on the provider's servers.

Comment: @albertdadze Endpoint application is the one that performs actual work. Instead of thread. Lets say, you have 20 threads spinning and then your service goes down - all your threads will remain uncompleted. But if you spin out an application, it will continue even if the service is down. Each app will run it its process so, there will be no need for you to do any thread management, which is not fun. At this pint, all your service need to do is to start right application with right parameters. Application itself will take care of progress, logging, etc

Comment: Thanks @MailmanOdd. Got appropriate feedback at StackExchange. You can check up the responses also at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225376/managing-child-worker-thread-list

Comment: Great, glad you got what you were looking for and welcome to StackExchange.